# create gradle multimodule project for AEM using lazybones templates

Tags: gradle, aem, project-structure, lazybones

I had heard of lazybones, which is a command line tool for project creation and it is more interactive or customizable than Maven Archetypes. Thus, I created a maven multimodule aem project using lazybones.

The Command and template for AEM multimodule project is:

`lazybones create aem-multimodule-project <target-folder>`

This creates a maven multimodule project for AEM. Then, I tried to find the same for Gradle, but I didn't find any template regarding that.

Can anyone give me any direction how can I achieve the same.

Comment: I don't think there is a lazybones aem template to create a gradle project. You may have to create your own template. Or ping [Justin](https://twitter.com/justinedelson) to check if he's created one.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using gradle aem plugin. It has a lot of features and might be good for your case
https://github.com/Cognifide/gradle-aem-plugin